# Error With CBitmapContextCreate, CGContextDrawImage, CGBitmapContextCreateImage

Tags: iphone, cgcontext, cgbitmapcontextcreate

Error: CGBitmapContextCreate: invalid data bytes/row: should be at least 400 for 8 integer bits/component, 3 components, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst.

Error: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context

Error: CGBitmapContextCreateImage: invalid context

Currently, I have in application that runs perfectly in OS 4.0, but I have been trying to get it to work properly in 3.1.3 and I keep getting the errors mentioned above.

I am fairly new to iPhone development and am not exactly sure what the problem would be. I am using image resize code that I found in another post on stackoverflow.

Here is the code:

```
- (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)sourceImage scaledToSizeWithSameAspectRatio:(CGSize)targetSize{  
CGSize imageSize = sourceImage.size;
CGFloat width = imageSize.width;
CGFloat height = imageSize.height;
CGFloat targetWidth = targetSize.width;
CGFloat targetHeight = targetSize.height;
CGFloat scaleFactor = 0.0;
CGFloat scaledWidth = targetWidth;
CGFloat scaledHeight = targetHeight;
CGPoint thumbnailPoint = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0);

if (CGSizeEqualToSize(imageSize, targetSize) == NO) {
    CGFloat widthFactor = targetWidth / width;
    CGFloat heightFactor = targetHeight / height;

    if (widthFactor > heightFactor) {
        scaleFactor = widthFactor; // scale to fit height
    }
    else {
        scaleFactor = heightFactor; // scale to fit width
    }

    scaledWidth  = width * scaleFactor;
    scaledHeight = height * scaleFactor;

    // center the image
    if (widthFactor > heightFactor) {
        thumbnailPoint.y = (targetHeight - scaledHeight) * 0.5; 
    }
    else if (widthFactor < heightFactor) {
        thumbnailPoint.x = (targetWidth - scaledWidth) * 0.5;
    }
}     

CGImageRef imageRef = [sourceImage CGImage];
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceInfo = CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef);

if (bitmapInfo == kCGImageAlphaNone) {
    bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;
}

CGContextRef bitmap;

if (sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp || sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
    bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, targetWidth, targetHeight, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef), colorSpaceInfo, bitmapInfo);

} else {
    bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, targetHeight, targetWidth, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef), colorSpaceInfo, bitmapInfo);

}       

// In the right or left cases, we need to switch scaledWidth and scaledHeight,
// and also the thumbnail point
if (sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
    thumbnailPoint = CGPointMake(thumbnailPoint.y, thumbnailPoint.x);
    CGFloat oldScaledWidth = scaledWidth;
    scaledWidth = scaledHeight;
    scaledHeight = oldScaledWidth;

    CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, radians(90));
    CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, 0, -targetHeight);

} else if (sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
    thumbnailPoint = CGPointMake(thumbnailPoint.y, thumbnailPoint.x);
    CGFloat oldScaledWidth = scaledWidth;
    scaledWidth = scaledHeight;
    scaledHeight = oldScaledWidth;

    CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, radians(-90));
    CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, -targetWidth, 0);

} else if (sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {
    // NOTHING
} else if (sourceImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
    CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, targetWidth, targetHeight);
    CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, radians(-180.));
}

CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(thumbnailPoint.x, thumbnailPoint.y, scaledWidth, scaledHeight), imageRef);
CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
UIImage* newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];

CGContextRelease(bitmap);
CGImageRelease(ref);

return newImage;
```

Any help would be appreciated. If you need more info, I will gladly post it.

Answer (score 0):

The first error is telling you that it is incorrect to pass `CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef)` as the row bytes of the new bitmap context.  The row byte count needs to be at least the width times the number of bytes per pixel.